# Why does Gluon plugin for Eclipse does not show up?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, gluon

I have Eclipse Photon Release (4.8.0) Build id 20180619-1200 with
- e(fx)clipse 3.3.0.201805280700
- Gluon 2.6.0.v20180424-0818 from Eclipse Marketplace

I followed the installation guide at http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.1/#eclipse-plugin but was not asked for any certificate acceptance or anything else and cannot create a new gluon project because gluon does not show up anywhere. Neither in new project nor in Preferences.

e(fx)clipse offers me a "Open with SceneBuilder" entry in the context menu of an fxml file.

Which step did I miss?

Comment: It works for me on a fresh install of Eclipse 2018-09. New project -> Gluon shows up.

Comment: You are right. After a fresh installation of Eclipse it even told me that my workspace was configured with an older version of Eclipse. After updating the workspace, the Gluon plugin worked as expected. Seems that Eclipse does not correctly update configurations and/ or plugins because all version looked same. Thx for the tip

Comment: But after installing e(fx)clipse from marketplace, Eclipse does not even start anymore. Problem seems to be that javax.xml.bind is not available for Eclipse?!?

Comment: Not related to this question. You need efxclipse 3.4.1

Comment: Installing efxclipse tries to restart eclipse after installation. Then I get an error dialog box and Eclipse does not even start anymore. Did you bring efxclipse running together with Eclipse? I'm using openjdk 11.0.1

Comment: Again, this is the wrong post for other questions. Yes, I have e(fx)clipse 3.4.1 working with Eclipse 2018-09 and JDK 11.